# {parent.uri}/{slug}

Tags: control-panel, craft3

In Craft 2.x you have the option of setting the top-level entries URL format for a structure section separately from nested entries i.e. `top-level/{slug}` and `{parent.uri}/{slug}`

But in Craft 3 the same URL format is applied for all entries within the structure section.

This means if you use `top-level/{parent.uri}/{slug}` it works fine for a top-level entry but then nested entries have the first segment duplicated, e.g. top-level/top-level/some-parent/the-slug. How does one achieve the same level of URL formatting for structure entries in Craft 3?

Comment: This worked for me...
https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/nested-entries-in-craft-3?newreg=dc9615a7c8bd4bac9fd5208438927108

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To pull off the same functionality in Craft 3, you could use something like this:

```
{entry.last().uri}/{parent.uri}/{slug}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Brad. Might be worth somehow including this in the CP field instructions for a structure or elsewhere in the craft doco as I would assume most people would want this format for a structure section. :)

Comment: I ended up using the following: `{% if level == 1 %}{section.handle}{% else %}{parent.uri}{% endif %}/{slug}`

Comment: the accepted answer turned out faulty on my craft 3 version. I ended up using `{parent.uri ?? 'top-level'}/{slug}` and solved my issue of duplicated segments while allowing for a fixed segment. The solution of Rich could be rewritten as `{parent.uri ?? section.handle}/{slug}` for readability purposes

Comment: 3xil3 has the correct answer.

Comment: After trying all answers here and at the related question here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/26483/4060 , the only answer that seems to allow for a static, non-duplicated segment in the url is here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/26484/4060

Comment: This seems to be very complicated for what would ideally be a fairly mundane setting, coming back to Craft after a few months off I'm quite confused as to how to get this working at all!