# Nested Entries in Craft 3

Tags: entries, craft3, structure

In Craft 2 there used to be a `Nested Entries` field, but this is not available in Craft 3.

I know I can do `{parent.uri}/{slug}` in the `Entry URI Format` field, but if I want it to be appended by something static it doesn't work.

i.e. `static/{parent.uri}/{slug}` doesn't work because children uri sets to `static/static/parent/child` (edited)

Answer (score 9):

I kind of found a work around, but doesn't seem like it's the correct way to be doing this.

`{parent.uri ? parent.uri : 'static'}/{slug}`

Comment: This is the only answer that seems to allow for a non-duplicated static segment in the url after trying all answers displayed here and also at the related question here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23610/parent-uri-slug

Comment: This worked best for me as well. It should be marked as the official answer

Answer (score 2):

Reviving this quite late, but the docs state the following as the correct method:

`{parent.uri}/{slug}`