# URI for nested categories in Craft 3

Tags: craft3, categories

I am trying to set up the URIs for some nested categories in Craft 3 but am having some issues. My structure is basically:

```
service-one
|-subservice-one-a
|-subservice-one-b
service-two
|-subservice-two-a
|-subservice-two-b
```

I have set my `Category URI Format` to:

`what-we-do/{slug}`

Which is working fine, however I would like the URI for the nested categories to look like:

`what-we-do/service-one/subservice-one-a`

rather than what I have currently:

`what-we-do/subservice-one-a`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can actually use a bit of Twig logic to determine your category URI formats.

Try this for your **Category URI Format**:

`{parent ? parent.uri : 'what-we-do'}/{slug}`

Which is just a more compact way of doing this:

```
{% if parent %}{{ parent.uri }}{% else %}what-we-do{% endif %}/{slug}
```

That will only add 'what-we-do' to the URI if the current category doesn't have a parent (top-level category). Otherwise, it prepends the entire parent's URI.

That should give you URIs like:

```
/what-we-do/service-one
/what-we-do/service-one/subservice-one-a
/what-we-do/service-one/subservice-one-b
/what-we-do/service-one/subservice-one-b/subservice-one-b-nested
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set your Category URI Format to `{parent.slug}/{slug}`

If they are on the parent it will only show the parent category. If they are on the child it will show both.

So you'd set it to

```
what-we-do/{parent.slug}/{slug}
```

There is also this answer if you need the path beyond 1 level:

[{parent.uri}/{slug}](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23610/parent-uri-slug?rq=1)

Comment: If you do that Darryl you end up with tld.com/what-we-do/what-we-do/category-parent/category-child.